# MS sync with WCF: The request operation did not complete within the allotted timeout of 00:01:00

Tags: c#, wcf

I'm quite new to Sync Framework, but I have quite a challenging task at hand...we are developing an application to sync client/server databases where we need to use HTTP protocol (using services) to access the server database. I am getting this exception

> The request channel timed out while waiting for a reply after 00:00:55.1217210. Increase the timeout value passed to the call to Request or increase the SendTimeout value on the Binding. The time allotted to this operation may have been a portion of a longer timeout.

**StackTrace:**

> Server stack trace: 
>      at System.ServiceModel.Channels.RequestChannel.Request(Message message, TimeSpan timeout)
>      at System.ServiceModel.Dispatcher.RequestChannelBinder.Request(Message message, TimeSpan timeout)
>      at System.ServiceModel.Channels.ServiceChannel.Call(String action, Boolean oneway, ProxyOperationRuntime operation, Object[] ins, Object[] outs, TimeSpan timeout)
>      at System.ServiceModel.Channels.ServiceChannelProxy.InvokeService(IMethodCallMessage methodCall, ProxyOperationRuntime operation)
>      at System.ServiceModel.Channels.ServiceChannelProxy.Invoke(IMessage message)
>
> Exception rethrown at [0]: 
>      at System.Runtime.Remoting.Proxies.RealProxy.HandleReturnMessage(IMessage reqMsg, IMessage retMsg)
>      at System.Runtime.Remoting.Proxies.RealProxy.PrivateInvoke(MessageData& msgData, Int32 type)
>      at AutoCrib.Sync.AppService.IService1.GetChanges(UInt32 batchSize, SyncKnowledge destinationKnowledge)
>      at AutoCrib.Sync.UI.RelationalProviderProxy.GetChangeBatch(UInt32 batchSize, SyncKnowledge destinationKnowledge, Object& changeDataRetriever) in d:\ASPSync7.0\ASPSync7.0\AutoCrib.Sync.WinForm\RelationalProviderProxy.cs:line 92
>      at Microsoft.Synchronization.KnowledgeProviderProxy.GetChangeBatch(UInt32 dwBatchSize, ISyncKnowledge pSyncKnowledge, ISyncChangeBatch& ppChangeBatch, Object& ppUnkDataRetriever)

**Server Web.Config**

```
<wsHttpBinding>
  <binding name="largeMessageHttpBinding"   maxReceivedMessageSize="1004857600" maxBufferPoolSize="1004857600" closeTimeout="00:1:00"
 openTimeout="00:1:00" receiveTimeout="00:1:00" >sendTimeout="00:1:00">
 <readerQuotas maxArrayLength="2147483647" maxBytesPerRead="2147483647"/>
  enter code here`<security mode="None"/>
          <reliableSession enabled="true" inactivityTimeout="00:00:59"/>
        </binding>
      </wsHttpBinding>
```

Comment: Your call has timed out, so you should increase the timeouts as in the error message. What's the question here?

Comment: I am Using MS sync framework with WCF to expose the server database. When i call orchestrator.Synchronize() method, Framework internally calls "GetChanges" of WCF method. I am getting the timeout error during the execution of this function. I have already increased the timeout but still getting the same error.

Comment: If you have increased the timeout and you still get the error, please show that in your question, where the timeout value is `"00:1:00"`